# Deploy Spring Security SAML extension as a stand alone module

Tags: spring-security

I'm doing some research about Spring Security SAML extension because we have several Spring applications that need to integrate with SSO (SimpleSamlPHP).

Although there are several applications, they belong to a unique system from a functional perspective and all of them will run in the same server.

I'm reading the reference documentation, in particular the point "6 - Integration to applications" and it says:

> SAML module can be directly embedded into new or existing Spring applications. In this case 
>   application itself includes the SAML library in WEB-INF/lib directory of the war archive and 
>   processes all SAML interactions. The other option of using the SAML library is deploying it as a 
>   stand-alone module which transfers information about the authenticated user to the target 
>   application using a custom mechanism. This chapter only discusses the first option.

I think that the stand alone option could be interesting in our situation. Does anybody know how to proceed with this option? How to deploy the SAML library as a stand-alone module? How to integrate the applications with this stand-alone module?

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to use SAML technology as a way to get data from users. I'm not interesting in using it as the only way to Sign In in my application (Service Provider), or even integrate it with my Spring Boot/Security stack that is already working. I just need to let user log in into some Identity Provider (or many of them), and the login callback be some Rest API I have.